# Is there a way to give each subset from a dataframe a different object name within an R function?

Tags: r, function, replace, rename

I need to make different subsets from one data.frame, and then use these different subsets for subsequent actions. 
Therefore, I need to give each subset a unique name. I tried writing different functions but could not figure out how.
Here I show the function for one subset, i.e. *datsub*:

```
run_subsets <- function(data, t, x) {
  datsub <- data[eval(substitute(t),data), ]
}
run_subsets(data=dat, t=type=="AM", x=datsub1)
```

But I need to have different names for each different subset, so next to *datsub", e.g.,
*datsub1*
*datsub2*, etc
What I tried already:

```
run_subsets <- function(data, t, x) {
  datsub <- data[eval(substitute(t),data), ]
  x <- datasub
}
run_subsets(data=dat, t=type=="AM", x=datsub1)
```

```
run_subsets <- function(data, t, x) {
  datsub <- data[eval(substitute(t),data), ]
  gsub("b", "x", "datsub")
run_subsets(data=dat, t=type=="AM", x=b1)
```

```
run_subsets <- function(data, t, x) {
  datsub <- data[eval(substitute(t),data), ]
  list(substitute(x)) <- datsub
run_subsets(data=dat, t=type=="AM", x=datsub1)
```

```
run_subsets <- function(data, t, x) {
  datsub <<- data[eval(substitute(t),data), ]
  data_name <- paste("datsub", x, sep=".")
  assign(data_name, datsub)
  save(list = data_name, file = paste0("datsub", scenario, ".Rdata"))
}
run_subsets(data=dat, t=type=="AM", x=datsub1)
```

and with `quote()` and these also in combination with `eval()`, and many others.
Could somebody help me?

Thank you in advance,

Roberto

PS I really searched a lot in internet and Stackoverflow and found a lot which looked promising but in this function it needs something else.

Comment: Typically results are assigned to a variable e.g. `datsub1 <- run_subsets(data=dat, t=type=="AM")`. Is this suitable?

Comment: You can create a `list of data.frames` and name each element of the `list` which is essentially, naming each `data.frame` separately. For that you will also have to keep a vector of `data.frame names` handy. What are the parameters you are using to subset the data.frames?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  What I need is an argument in the function which changes _datsub_ itself in the body of the function. The idea is that I have three arguments:  one for the data.frame (_data_), one for the condition (_t_), and one for changing _datsub_ in datsub1 etc  (_x_).  This way I can say for instance: I want to select a dataframe with such a condition and name it this way. So, how can I create an argument for changing _datasub_ itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
# create a dataframe
df <- data.frame(
    a = 1:10
    , b = letters[1:10]
)

# the function that subsets the dataframe and gives it a name
# and assigns it to the name you chose
run_subsets <- function(data, t, x) {
    assign(
        x
        , data[eval(substitute(t),data), ]
        , envir = .GlobalEnv
    )
}
```

Of course, you have to make sure, you write it into the correct environment. I just chose the global environment here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're better off creating the subsets on the fly. One solution could be that you create a dataframe with "subsetting" columns like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
    a = 1:10
    , b = letters[1:10]
)

subsets <- data.frame(
    datsub1 = df$b == "d"
    , datsub2 = df$a < 5
)

df[subsets$datsub1, ]
df[subsets$datsub2, ]
```

You can also create the "subsetting" columns in the same dataframe. That's what I usually do to keep my workspace clean.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  What I need is an argument in the function which changes _datsub_ itself in the body of the function. The idea is that I have three arguments:  one for the data.frame (_data_), one for the condition (_t_), and one for changing _datsub_ in datsub1 etc  (_x_).  This way I can say for instance: I want to select a dataframe with such a condition and name it this way. So, how can I create an argument for changing _datasub_ itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ldf = split.data.frame(x = dat,f = dat$type)
```

Then you can apply your function to each of the separate `data.frame` like this:

```
lapply(ldf, function(x){ someFunc(x) })
```